# Missing required parameters for route (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, forms

I'm trying to recreate a blog application form old laravel version in new version (5.8). In old version, I used laravel collective for forms, and my edit post form looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title', $post->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
            {{Form::textarea('body', $post->body, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}            
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Now I'm trying to recreate the same form without laravel collective forms because it seems to be deprecated.

This is my attempt at recreating this form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Edit post</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('posts.update'), $post->id }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value={{$post->title}}>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3" name="body" value={{$post->body}}></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
@endsection
```

I'm getting the following error:
`Missing required parameters for [Route: posts.update] [URI: posts/{post}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\posts\edit.blade.php)`

Looks like I'm not sending the id parameter correctly.

Also,how can I recreate this part: `{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}` in plain HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate the `method` input with this:

```
@method('PUT')
```

You need to put the `$post->id` inside the `route()` and use the [Form method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) (`@method('PUT')`). Try this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Edit post</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('posts.update', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value={{$post->title}}>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="3" name="body" value={{$post->body}}></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is caused by `$post->id` being outside of the `route()` function.

Change:

```
route('posts.update'), $post->id
```

to:

```
route('posts.update', $post)
```

---

As for the second question, this is how `Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')` is rendered as HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

But you can use `@method` if you prefer a shorter way of writing it:

```html
<form action="{{ route('posts.update', $post) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```